# Using Mongo_Dart how to get lists of database-names, and collections (given db)

Tags: mongodb, dart

In the shell I can do this: **show dbs**  to list all 'databases' on the connection.  How can I do this using mongo_dart commands?

In the shell I can do this: **show collections** (names) on a given database.  How can I do this using mongo_dart commands?

I'm stumped, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After some googling and looking at the [mongo_dart API](http://vadimtsushko.github.io/mongo_dart/mongo_dart.html) and [examples](https://github.com/vadimtsushko/mongo_dart/tree/master/example) I came to the conclusion that it is currently **not possible** to do such thing with this library.

Comment: Thanks for researching!  Have now have fallen back on using a Mongo_Ruby interface which seems to be more complete. Doing some pretty tricky things, performance seems great, but have not found commands to do these things directly yet either.  Perhaps I can pull an old trick and direct some shell queries to text files and read those, but that seems like overkill.  I still think these are basic commands that would enable better ("reflective") coding techniques. Thanks for the kind effort!

Answer (score 1):

I've just added two helpers to `Db` class: `listDatabases()` and `listCollections()`
Both return `Future<List<String>>`, hopefully that would be usefull to you.
Effective in v0.1.40

Comment: Большое спасибо, Bal'shoye spaseeba.    Should be exactly what I need.  I am using Mongolab dbs like big "log files" of all db edit transactions (CUD).  It looks like this is going to work out well as it is super fast and now I can use the same memory scheme at the server that I am using in the client.